# how to list suspended rstudio server sessions?

Tags: rstudio-server

I know I can list active sessions using `sudo rstudio-server active-sessions`, but is there any way to list suspended sessions? I'm working with the free version of RStudio Server.

My ultimate goal is to kill suspended sessions to better manage memory on a shared-use VM. If there is a cleaner way to do this I'm all ears, but I think a combination of listing suspended sessions and killing them in a chron job that runs periodically will meet my needs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there's currently no formal way to do this; suspended sessions do not exist in any global table. They are saved privately to user's home directories and can only be read by the user who owns the session.

Suspended sessions also don't consume any memory, so enumerating them may not help you manage memory.

That said, if your cron job has root access, it is pretty easy to find suspended sessions; just enumerate your user `HOME` folders and look in `~/.rstudio/sessions` for each user.